# IComparable<T> Does not Implement

Tags: c#, icomparable

I've changed from using `IComparable` to `IComparable<Artist>` However I'm getting the error

> 'RecordCollection.Artist' does not implement interface member 'System.IComparable.CompareTo(object)'

```
class Artist : IComparable<Artist>
```

I've added a CompareTo method.

Not sure what this error means, any help describing why I'm getting this would be great.

```
class Artist : IComparable<Artist>
{
    private String Name;
    private int NoMem;

    public Artist(string Name, int NoMem)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.NoMem = NoMem; 
    }

 public int CompareTo(Artist other)
    {
        if (other == null) return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

New Artist AVL tree

```
        AVLTree<Artist> treeAVL = new AVLTree<Artist>();
```

Comment: I assume you mean: I've changed from using IComparable to IComparable<T> ?

Comment: Also show your CompareTo method ... probably it misses the <T> part.

Comment: @J.Steen: The actual question (at least mine :-) ) is why it would be required, given that he's only implementing `IComparable<Artist>`, not `IComparable`. (Note that `IComparable<T>` does not inherit from `IComparable`.)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Yeah, I know - it only has int CompareTo(T other). Which that method *should* satisfy, so I'm guessing the compiler error is out of whack for some other reason.

Comment: Please show a minimal class that shows this. For example, did you *replace* the `IComparable` with `IComparable<T>`, or did you *append* `IComparable<T>`. Is `IComparable` requested in another part of a `partial` class, for example.

Comment: This is not the answer but will help you what you are missing. If you move your mouse cursor to IComparable<Artist> it will show a little dialog. It will say implement this interface. You click that then VS will write all the missing functions at the bottom. Go there and write implemenation of these.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers there *is* no `<T>` in the implementation; you can't implement an interface method that is non-generic via a generic method

Comment: @FaisalHafeez you know the IDE has at least two different "implement interface" options to do this for you, right?

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeah it can. But it will help to find out which one is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make sure your project in which you define `Artist` compiles without errors. Otherwise your other projects won't pick up the change and still think `Artist` implements `IComparable` instead of `IComparable<T>`. That's when you get the compile-time error:

> 'RecordCollection.Artist' does not implement interface member 'System.IComparable.CompareTo(object)'

There is no technical need to implement `CompareTo(object)` also, and it won't fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have copied and pasted that error, it looks like you should implement `CompareTo` like this:

```
public int CompareTo(object other)
{
    if (other == null) return 1;
        else
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The message:

> 'RecordCollection.Artist' does not implement interface member 'System.IComparable.CompareTo(object)'

clearly states that it thinks your class still declares that it implements `IComparable` somewhere. You might want to seek that out (it could be in a different file via `partial class`). However, personally I think it is correct to include non-typed support. I would simply add:

```
int IComparable.CompareTo(object obj)
{
    return CompareTo(obj as Artist);
}
```